# FTP Disturbing NAT Server Connection

Tags: linux, tcp, ftp, iptables

It's a very strange problem. I have a Ubuntu 12.04 server **A** with KVM (Kernel Virtual Machine), proftpd and MySQL installed and UFW configured. An guest Ubuntu 12.04 **B** with OpenVPN and phpMyAdmin installed and another guest Ubunutu 12.04 **C** with Tomcat7 installed. I'm using my laptop **D** which is connected to **B** with OpenVPN and **D** is connecting to **A** through **B** (iptables masquerade). And here is the problem:

I've written a Java program using commons-net-3.1-ftp to backup the FTP storage from **A**. And when this backup program is running on **D**, **B** cannot connect to any of the services running on **A** (ftp, MySQL, etc.) while **B** is able to ping **A** and both **C** and **D** are able to connect to **A**. But I've tried another FTP client, FlashFXP, to download something from **A** to **D** and in such situation, **B** is able to connect to **A**.

I've checked the log files but nothing can be found. I've also tried tcpdump on **A** and **B** and I found that when the FTP backup is running, **A** can receive the package from **B**, however, **A** won't respond to **B**.

I really need your help to solve this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Sounds a bit complicated ... I would at first sniff the network traffic with tcpdump or wireshark. What tool do you have?

Comment: I'd like to try any tool to solve this problem. I've tried tcpdump as described above.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to sniff the networktraffic from B to A

   sudo tcpdump -A -n -s 0 -w test_ftp.log host IP_OF_HOST_A
2. Start backup on D
3. Try to use your desired service of A from B. Try for debugging also a normal http request
4. Stop tcpdump
5. Check test_ftp.log with wireshark

Comment: @bestmike007 if you interested can you send me the test_ftp.log

Comment: Hi! Here is the [dump.log](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BzVcPv1uiIeuUEwxQlREaGtfdHM).

Comment: @bestmike007 uff - that's hard, I read the network situation again. To get you right ... your backup program goes via the vpn and B to your machine A. And you have a NAT network? So A, B, C are in the same sub net. Is your VPN between D and B every time connected or only when your backup program is running? Can B connect to A if the VPN is established and the backup program not run?

Comment: Yes, NAT network for D via VPN and A, B, C are in the same sub net. There is a persistent VPN connection between D and B so that D can connect to A at any moment. B cannot connect to A iff the backup program is running, regardless of the state of the VPN connection.